# filter in requests in ascending order in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import pyperclip
import time
from threading import Thread
token = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
count = 0
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

def get_source_html(url):
    responce = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    time.sleep(10)
    with open("projects.html", 'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(responce.text)


def get_items_urls(file_path):
    with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        src=file.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
    items_divs= soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'market_table_value normal_price')

    urls = []
    for item in items_divs:
        item_url = item.find("span",class_='normal_price')
        urls.append(item_url)
    
    with open("items_fls.txt",'w') as file:
        for url in urls:
            if float(url.text[1:-4])<3.24:
                file.write(f"price:{url.text}\n")

 
def main():
    while count<5:
        get_source_html(url="https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=%22Fnatic%20Boston%202018%22&descriptions=1&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Quality%5B%5D=#p1_price_asc")
        get_items_urls(file_path='D:\python\Новая папка\projects.html')
        with open('items_fls.txt') as file:
            data=file.read()
        pyperclip.copy(data)
        print(data)
        requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendmessage'.format(token), params=dict(chat_id='802613449', text=data))
        time.sleep(120)
f __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target=main).start()
```

Why, when running python code, does not send the request to the entire link. It ignores #p1_price_asc. This is a filter on the site itself that allows you to place offers in ascending order. Help, what should I do? I tried to search for the answer on other sites, but I didn't find anything like that.

I tried to search for the answer on other sites, but I didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're facing is related to how URLs work in HTTP requests. The part of the URL after the # symbol, in your case, `#p1_price_asc`, is called a [fragment identifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20fragment%20identifier&client=safari&sca_esv=578522338&rls=en&ei=O3hCZZ7-HrioptQP2MmWqAg&ved=0ahUKEwjeh-j4l6OCAxU4lIkEHdikBYUQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=what%20is%20fragment%20identifier&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiG3doYXQgaXMgZnJhZ21lbnQgaWRlbnRpZmllcjIEEAAYRzIEEAAYRzIEEAAYRzIEEAAYRzIEEAAYRzIEEAAYRzIEEAAYRzIEEAAYR0isHFD3BFjzG3AAeAKQAQCYAQCgAQCqAQC4AQPIAQD4AQHiAwQYACBBiAYBkAYI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp). Fragments are not sent to the server when making an HTTP request, and they are typically used for navigation or client-side functionality in web browsers. Therefore, when you use the URL with `#p1_price_asc` in your Python code, it won't affect the server's response because it's not being sent to the server and you won't get the response that you hoped for.

### Use selenium instead:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Initialize a headless browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Navigate to the Steam Community Market page
url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=%22Fnatic%20Boston%202018%22&descriptions=1&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Quality%5B%5D="
driver.get(url)

# Apply the filter using JavaScript
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#p1_price_asc').click()")

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(10)

# Get the page source with the filter applied
page_source = driver.page_source

# Don't forget to close the browser when you're done
driver.quit()
```